# how to have a discord bot remove a specifc emoji reaction (python)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I've looked around and I haven't seen a answer yet so thought I would ask. I've tried some code but it hasn't worked yet. This is what I have tried so far...

```
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add():
   if reaction.emoji == "":
     await remove.reaction()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were really close! It's `reaction.remove`

```py
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add():
    if reaction.emoji == "":
        await reaction.remove()
```

#### Reference:

- [`Reaction.remove`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Reaction.remove)